# Android : react-native-maps show only absolute one block area in detail

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

***Android : react-native-maps show only absolute one block area in detail.***

Only one rectangular area is shown in detail.

I try code.but Does not get better

What's wrong with this?
When I zoom in on the map, I can't see anything, does this mean it crashes?
ios is working fine.

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
 android:value="*********************"/>
 <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**result**
I solved it by enabling google api (ios android).

**Cause**
*Why this problem happened*
At first, I only enabled the api of js. The reason is that I thought that the api key can be used as it is (ios, android) because the character string is the same. AHA